# How can I use document.getElementById(someid).onclick for tag a

Tags: javascript, html, automation, jscript

I want to automate to click on some link in a website.

since links on webpage are not direct link such as www.example.com/1.html.

it shows following link address for all the links I am interested in clicking

```
javascript:void(1)
```

following is the html code for that link I want to click

```
<a href="javascript:void(1)" onclick="server_playOn(17,2, 'est', this);">
                     Life OK  
                  </a>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for including the [jscript] tag ?

Comment: I would like to make a jscript.js files, which I can call from `AHK` AutoHotKey to do the clicking, I am wrong you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've got a reference to the link you can just use the click method:

```
referenceToLink.click();
```

Comment: I don't know how to get reference to the link. by that you mean direct link correct?

Comment: I mean to create a variable that refers to this a-link element. It doesn't have an id so you'll have to navigate to it in some other way.

Comment: I am very noob to what you are referring to sorry.